# Multidimensional arrays with different dimensional values in Java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

Is there any way build an array in Java such that it can possess multiple dimensions in different indexes? For example: in JSON I would write such array as:

```
//jsonObj.jsonc
[
    [
        [
            “String”,
            ”String2”
        ],
        “String3”
    ]
    “String4”
]
```

If it helps, I’m trying to build something to decode basic JSON. Everything is sorted at this point but I don’t know how to set up an array this way, or if there’s an alternative

I tried to use new objects from a class to build arrays, but this also has the dimension limiter. I’m new here, please let me know if I’m missing a basic.

Comment: It would help if you showed how you access that data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be an array of `Object`, where each object can be another array, or just a `String`, `Number` or `Boolean` object. But doing that in Java is rather cumbersome, as it requires lots of `instanceof` and casts. Using `List`s instead of arrays makes things *slightly* easier.

Comment: I was messing around with custom data-storing files, I realized that I can get better results if I navigate to JSON instead. I was really just trying to make a universal JSON object in Java when there are extensions that can do it for me without the headache

Comment: Definitely. Just use a JSON library and call it a day.